# Can Unity and Flash communicate between eachother if they coexists in the browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, communication, unity-game-engine, bidirectional

In other words, can Flash trigger methods in Unity if both are present on a webpage, and both are setup with some exposed methods to talk to eachother?

Would JavaScript be the middle-man doing the communication between the two?

I'm thinking that Flash would use ExternalInterface and Unity would use something else (I'm not familiar enough with it).

Just curious if that would be possible, in theory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like unity has methods for talking to JavaScript, similar to as3. It would definitely be possible using JS

```
Application.ExternalCall( "SayHello", "The game says hello!" );
```

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Unity%20Web%20Player%20and%20browser%20communication.html

Comment: Thanks @f-a, I also found this neat slide presentation that explains how to set this up (on Unity3D, Javascript and Flash ActionScript 3.0.) ~ 35 slides. 
http://www.slideshare.net/paultondeur/unity-and-flash-the-best-of-both-worlds-unite-presentation-slides